# How to make a button of the same physical size on desktop and mobile?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an upcoming project where it is crucial to have elements (e.g. a button) showing up with the physical identical size (e.g. 3 cm) across different devices with different heights, widths, display aspect ratios (4:3, 16:9), device pixel ratios and dpi.  How can I do this with HTML + CSS (+ JavaScript)?

In order to have responsive design I set the viewport for all my devices:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Now it's possible to use media queries to layout my website on different devices. However, when I define a button class with a fixed height/width, it shows up in a different physical sizes (e.g. on my MacOS Chrome and iOS Safari).

```
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

I know about CSS pixels vs physical pixels. Still, the button shows up with a different size on my devices. Is there any way to display the button with the exact same physical size on different devices without writing media queries for each device (because that's a bad practice)?

Comment: Well css3 defines physical sizes such as [mm or cm](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), but making them work consistently across browsers and devices might be quite a headache without some sort of calibration first.

Comment: what if the user zooms in? It is nearly impossible to make it the exact same physical size on every device, since all of those controls are on the client-side.  When exact real-world dimensions are a requirement for our project we have to start asking if this design is right

Comment: not to mention accessibility options at the OS level - if I have a vision impairment or unsteady motor control, I may set my OS to make every element on the screen 2x bigger so it's easier to read or interact with.  A website will have a very difficult time overriding that sort of thing

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, for a simple reason:

1rst device: video-projector = image is 250cm/175cm, resolution is 1920*1080
2nd device: ipad3 = retina screen image is 240mm/180mm, resolution is 2048*1536

Have you tried to define your sizes in **inch**?

```
width: 1.25in;
height: .75in;
```